# Сделать так,чтобы текст не заходил на псевдокласс before

Tags: css, css3

Текст заходит на псевдоэлемент before, как это можно исправить? Элементарная вещь, а решить не получается.

```css
.products {
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px;
   width: 210px;
   height: 25px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.products:before {
   content: ">";
   width: 14px;
   height: 8px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Liner</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
 <div class="products">
  Привет как дела что делаешь?
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Убрать `position:absolute` у псевдоэлемента. Или можно задать блоку `padding-right`.

Comment: Точно-точно, вот за это спасибо, из головы совсем вылетело

Comment: И если нужно поместить скобку справа - лучше использовать `:after`

Answer (score 0):

```
.products {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.products:before  {
  content: ">";
  width: 14px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="products">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum, impedit tempore molestiae recusandae voluptatem molestias odio distinctio iusto aliquid eligendi iure fugiat esse, quidem reiciendis sit voluptatibus quo libero nesciunt facilis. Ipsam, est similique. Cupiditate accusantium quibusdam debitis distinctio quas nesciunt eum, adipisci voluptas commodi nostrum quaerat qui maxime.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению нельзя, а если символов будет больше?Что-то вроде overflow бы применить.

Comment: "а если символов будет больше".. зачем тогда вы задаете фиксированную высоту для блока?